# Interprocess Memory Editing - Finding changed addresses

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory

I'm currently making one of those game trainers as a small project. I've already ran into a problem; when you "go into a different level", the addresses for things such as fuel, cash, bullets, their addresses change. This would also happen say, if you were to restart the application.

How can I re-locate these addresses?

I feel like it's a fairly basic question, but it's one of those "it is or is not possible" questions to me. Should I just stop looking and forget the concept entirely? "Too hard?"

Comment: How do you locate them in the first instance?

Comment: What do you mean by "re-locating addresses"?

Comment: You find addresses from other people (sort of hard, considering this is dynamic..) or you search in the memory for the value. Your money is 50,000? Think it's a unsigned int? Search for 50000 in the memory, and then find the right one. By re-locating them, I'm talking about address change. The pointer to the money changes each level, and it changes every single time you start the program.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to describe exactly how to do this since it heavily dependents on the program you're studying and whether the author went out if his way to make your life difficult. Note that I've only done this once but it worked reasonably well even if I only knew a little assembly.

What is probably happening is that the values are allocated on the heap using a call to malloc/new and everytime you change level they are cleaned up and re-allocated somewhere else. So the idea is to look at the assembly code of the program to find where the pointer returned by malloc is stored and figure out a way to reliably read the content of the pointer and find the value you're looking for.

First thing you'll want is a debugger like [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) and a basic knowledge of assembly.  After that, start by setting a read and write breakpoint on the variable you want to examine. Since you said that you can't tell exactly where the variable is, you'll have to pause the process while it's running and search the program's memory for the value. Hopefully you'll end up with only a few results to sift through but be suspicious of anything that is on the stack since it might just be a copy for a function call or for local use.

Once the breakpoint is set just run the program until a break occurs. Now all you have to do is look at the code and examine how the variable is being accessed. If it's being passed as a parameter, go examine the call site of the function. If it's being accessed through a pointer, make a note of it and start examining the pointer. If it's being accessed as an offset of a pointer, that means it's part of a data structure so make a note of it and start examining the other variable. And so on.

Stay focused on your variable and just keep examining the code until you eventually find the root which can be one of two things:

- A global variable that has a static address. This is the easiest scenario since you have a static address hardcoded straight into the code that you can use to reliably walk through the data structures.
- A stack allocated variable. This is trickier and I'm not entirely sure how to deal with this scenario reliably. It's possible that its address will have the same offset from the beginning of the stack most of the time but it might not. You could also walk the stack to find the corresponding function and its parameters but this a bit tricky to get right.

Once you have an address all that's left to do is use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553.aspx) to locate your variable using the information you found. For example, if the address you have represents a pointer to a data structure where at offset 0x40 your fuel value is stored, then you'll have to read the value at the address, add 0x40 to it and do another read on the result.

Note that the address is only valid as long as the executable doesn't change in any way. If it's recompiled or patched then you have to start over. I believe you'll also have to be careful about Windows' [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) which might change the address around every time you start the program.

---

Comment box was too small to fit this so I'll put it here.

If it's `esp` plus a constant then I believe that this is a parameter and not a local variable (do confirm by checking the layout of the calling convention). If that's the case, then you should step the program until it returns to its caller, figure out how the parameter is being set (look for push instructions before the call instruction) and continue exploring from there. When I did this I had to unwind the stack once or twice before I found the global pointer to the data structure.

Also the `esi` register is not related to the stack (I had to [look it up](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html)) so I'd check how it's being set. It could be that it contains the address of the data structure and the constant is the offset to the variable. If you figure out how the register is set you'll be that much closer to the pointer.

Comment: Hey, I did some more researching and it is, unfortunately stack allocated. There are **no** static pointers to it at all. (And there's no pointer to the pointer) -- and yes; I've done it before also, but not with stack allocated variables. I do know that, say, money is [esi+a30] (a30 is **static**), so I know that points to what I want to edit -- but you can't ask a user to pull the address out of their butt. I also did some shoving around through the memory, and it appears the function only uses up 4 bytes of the stack (mov eax,[esp+04]). That's really all I know.

Comment: @Saustin Tiny comment box won't allow me to reply so I updated the answer instead. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Debugging a game by no means can be easy if there's threads and what-not, but I will try my best. Thanks for the response, I will continue to research.

Comment: @Saustin What you're doing is closer to reverse engineering than debugging but that doesn't really matter. Oh and don't forget to have fun :)